# Angular ng-repeat to create images - tries to resolve url too

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drupal

I'm using angular-drupal to get data from my Drupal backend. I'm trying to make an image gallery, from the out the box endpoints I get from services module, I'm calling node load to get a node. Then I'm targeting the images attached to that node, looping them and getting the file and sticking it in an array.

In my view I'm using ng-repeat to loop my loadedImages array and get the file uri to create an image.

Issue: ngRepeat goes immediately and the images are updated once the promise is resolved for each one, which is fine. The problem is I get a forbidden GET right at the top of the console because the view tries to render an image with just the placeholder:-

GET http://localhost/headless-test/app/%7B%7B::val.uri_full%7D%7D 403 (Forbidden)

Whats the best way to do this? I just don't want ng-repeat to try and make anything until my array has a value - at least I think that's the issue, any help would be appreciated. One more thing, this works, I get the images and I can see them - just don't want that GET error in the console.

Controller code:-

```
drupal.node_load(12).then(function(node) {
        console.log(node, "node returned");
        vm.loadedImages = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < node.field_test_image_3.und.length; i++) {
            drupal.file_load(node.field_test_image_3.und[i].fid).then(function(file) {
                vm.loadedImages.push(file);
                console.log(vm.loadedImages, "loaded images");
            });
        }
});
```

View:

```
<div ng-cloak>
    {{::vm.loadedImages}}
    <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in vm.loadedImages">
        <img src="{{::val.uri_full}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue I just updated the img 'src' to 'ng-src' and that solved it. Should of googled harder.